# SQL Server Database Engine Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to create a new database engine instance without having to install another instance of SQL Server?

I have been tasked to create a separate private instance of SQL Server which will be specifically used for Payroll data but cannot think of a way other than installing another instance of SQL.

Currently have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is SQL 2014?  We can't tell the product from your description.  And why not just use a different instance of your SQL server?

Comment: "without having to install" - are you simply trying to avoid the work of running through the installer, or something else? What is the goal of avoiding installing another instance?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - My apologies, the version I am currently on is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4057120) - 12.0.5214.6 (X64) 
 Jan  9 2018 15:03:12 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

I currently have several users which needs admin rights on SQL to be able to read/write data from 3rd party programs. How would I be able to create another instance on the current installation and restrict admin users to this db?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - No reason, just exploring what options are available. Would installing another instance be the best option? maybe the only?

Comment: Another instance is just another instance - it is not "on the current installation." You can administer permissions etc. completely independently.